# Angular filter is invoked, even when filter parameters do not change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular1.6

We have an Angular 1.6 filter that keeps firing all the time.

The HTML looks like:

```
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="(promptId, q) in (categoryDoubleFiltered = (categoryFiltered | 
    custom:searchText:selectAllCheckbox:answeredCheckbox))">
```

So there are 3 arguments being passed to the filter =>

```
searchText:selectAllCheckbox:answeredCheckbox
```

here is the filter:

```
app.filter('custom', function () {

  return function (input, search, selectAllCheckbox, selectAnswered) {

       console.log('filter is invoked!');
       // do our filtering thing

      // return some subset of input

   };

});
```

In our HTML for the (promptId, q) keys/values, we have the standard `ng-model` and `ng-click` stuff. But I don't see why the filter should ever be invoked, unless one of the inputs to the filter change!? The filter is even invoked when we hover over `<a>` tags.

What the heck? What can we do to stop it from be called so much?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using primitives, filters will fire multiple times per $digest. In this situation, it appears that you have infinite digests running. You can verify by using this to see if indeed you are running nonstop digests:

```
var digestCount = 0;

$rootScope.$watch(function() {
  digestCount++;
  console.log(digestCount);
});
```

I recommend you track down the cause of your infinite digests and fix it to get your filters working properly. Also a plunkr or fiddle might help us diagnose.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't to be infinite digest. The filters will stop, but then when we hover over HTML elements the filter will fire again. I'd like to stop the filter from firing if we are just hovering over HTML tags.